# How to groupby interval index, aggregate mean on a list of lists, and join to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes. They look like this:

```
df_a
     Framecount                                        probability
0           0.0  [0.00019486549333333332, 4.883635666666667e-06...
1           1.0  [0.00104359155, 3.9232405e-05, 0.0015722045000...
2           2.0  [0.00048501002666666667, 1.668179e-05, 0.00052...
3           3.0  [4.994969500000001e-05, 4.0931635e-07, 0.00011...
4           4.0  [0.0004808829, 5.389742e-05, 0.002522127933333...
..          ...                                                ...
906       906.0  [1.677140566666667e-05, 1.1745095666666665e-06...
907       907.0  [1.5164155000000002e-05, 7.66629575e-07, 0.000...
908       908.0  [8.1334184e-05, 0.00012675669636333335, 0.0028...
909       909.0  [0.00014893802999999998, 1.0407592500000001e-0...
910       910.0  [4.178489e-05, 2.17477925e-06, 0.02094931, 0.0...
```

And:

```
df_b
     start    stop
0     12.12   12.47
1     13.44   20.82
2     20.88   29.63
3     31.61   33.33
4     33.44   42.21
..      ...     ...
228  880.44  887.92
229  888.63  892.07
230  892.13  895.30
231  895.31  900.99
232  907.58  908.35
```

I want to merge `df_a.probability` onto `df_b` when `df_a.Framecount` is in between df_b.start and `df_b.stop`. The aggregation statistic for `df_a.probability` should be `mean`, but I run into errors because `df_a.probability` is dtype np array.

I am trying to using this code:

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_text['start'], df_text['stop'])
df_text.join(df_vid.groupby(idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount']))['probability'].apply(np.mean), how='left')
```

Line 1 creates the index do determine the grouping. In line 2 I am trying to implement the group by and aggregating all of the values in `df_a.probability` that fall within a groupby index by mean. I want one array per groupby that is the mean of all arrays in the groupby index. This code gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-271-19c7d58fb664> in <module>
      1 idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_text['start'], df_text['stop'])
      2 f = lambda x: np.mean(np.array(x.tolist()), axis=0)
----> 3 df_text.join(df_vid.groupby(idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount']))['probability'].apply(np.mean), how='left')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed)
   5808             group_keys=group_keys,
   5809             squeeze=squeeze,
-> 5810             observed=observed,
   5811         )
   5812 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated)
    407                 sort=sort,
    408                 observed=observed,
--> 409                 mutated=self.mutated,
    410             )
    411 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate)
    588 
    589         elif is_in_axis(gpr):  # df.groupby('name')
--> 590             if gpr in obj:
    591                 if validate:
    592                     obj._check_label_or_level_ambiguity(gpr, axis=axis)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __contains__(self, key)
   1848     def __contains__(self, key) -> bool_t:
   1849         """True if the key is in the info axis"""
-> 1850         return key in self._info_axis
   1851 
   1852     @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __contains__(self, key)
   3898     @Appender(_index_shared_docs["contains"] % _index_doc_kwargs)
   3899     def __contains__(self, key) -> bool:
-> 3900         hash(key)
   3901         try:
   3902             return key in self._engine

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I have tried multiple aggregation specifications, including:

```
df_text.join(df_vid.groupby(idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount']))['probability'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(np.array(x.tolist()), axis=0)), how='left')
```

or

```
df_text.join(df_vid.groupby(idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount']))['probability'].apply((np.mean), how='left')
```

or

```
df_text.join(df_vid.groupby(idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount']))['probability'].mean()), how='left')
```

and I get the same error.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The error occurs because `idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount'])` creates a `tuple`, and you can't `groupby` a tuple, in this way.

  - `df_vid.groupby(idx.get_indexer_non_unique(df_vid['Framecount'])[0])` selecting the first array in the `tuple` would work.
- `idx.get_indexer(df_a.fc)` will result in an array, with the index of the interval that `fc` belongs to. If there is not a matching interval, the index will show as `-1`.
- `df_a.groupby(idx.get_indexer(df_a.fc))` groups by an array of indices.
- `.agg({'prob': list})` aggreages all the lists, for each `fc`, into a list.

  - The result for each group, is a list of lists
- `.prob.map(np.mean)` returns the the overall mean, for all lists in the group
- `.prob.apply(lambda x: [np.mean(v) for v in x])` returns a list of means, for each list.
- No `'fc'` value falls into the bin for `12.12 - 12.47`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup df with start and stop ranges
data = {'start': [12.12, 13.44, 20.88, 31.61, 33.44, 880.44, 888.63, 892.13, 895.31, 907.58], 'stop': [12.47, 20.82, 29.63, 33.33, 42.21, 887.92, 892.07, 895.3, 900.99, 908.35]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# setup sample df_a with Framecount as fc, and probability as prob
np.random.seed(365)
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'fc': range(911), 'prob': np.random.randint(1, 100, (911, 14)).tolist()})

# this will convert the column to np.arrays instead of lists; the remainder of the code works regardless
# df_a.prob = df_a.prob.map(np.array)

# create an IntervalIndex from df start and stop
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.start, df.stop, closed='both')
```

#### This will create a list of means on axis=0

```py
dfg = df_a.groupby(idx.get_indexer(df_a.fc)).agg({'prob': list}).prob.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=0))

# join df with dfg
dfj = df.join(dfg)

# display(dfj) for list of means
    start    stop                                                                                  prob
0   12.12   12.47                                                                                   NaN
1   13.44   20.82  [49.3, 57.1, 51.4, 45.9, 47.1, 45.9, 45.9, 55.3, 32.6, 48.0, 42.0, 45.0, 50.4, 54.4]
2   20.88   29.63  [42.7, 42.6, 46.0, 45.9, 54.1, 55.9, 50.1, 55.2, 51.7, 54.0, 37.6, 60.9, 49.2, 45.6]
3   31.61   33.33  [87.5, 49.0, 46.5, 54.5, 75.0, 47.0, 24.0, 40.5, 52.5, 21.0, 51.0, 72.5, 34.5, 50.5]
4   33.44   42.21  [48.6, 66.2, 45.8, 64.7, 43.1, 69.0, 54.4, 52.1, 52.6, 59.6, 51.1, 42.1, 43.3, 38.0]
5  880.44  887.92  [51.9, 50.6, 63.7, 47.7, 51.3, 34.9, 51.3, 53.0, 53.4, 65.1, 38.6, 49.4, 48.1, 44.1]
6  888.63  892.07  [45.2, 23.5, 67.2, 68.0, 38.2, 47.2, 50.2, 75.8, 35.2, 46.8, 55.0, 57.5, 44.2, 78.0]
7  892.13  895.30  [61.3, 44.0, 43.3, 36.3, 63.7, 89.7, 51.7, 57.0, 50.0, 68.7, 80.7, 46.3, 66.7, 11.3]
8  895.31  900.99  [68.2, 44.6, 50.8, 35.2, 53.2, 40.4, 34.8, 77.4, 61.0, 35.2, 26.0, 47.8, 30.4, 55.4]
9  907.58  908.35     [17.0, 78.0, 24.0, 33.0, 88.0, 3.0, 43.0, 2.0, 36.0, 48.0, 8.0, 87.0, 36.0, 34.0]
```

#### This will create a single mean for each group

```py
dfg = df_a.groupby(idx.get_indexer(df_a.fc)).agg({'prob': list}).prob.map(np.mean)

# join df with dfg
dfj = df.join(dfg)

# display(dfj) for overall mean
    start    stop       prob
0   12.12   12.47        NaN
1   13.44   20.82  47.877551
2   20.88   29.63  49.380952
3   31.61   33.33  50.428571
4   33.44   42.21  52.182540
5  880.44  887.92  50.224490
6  888.63  892.07  52.303571
7  892.13  895.30  55.047619
8  895.31  900.99  47.171429
9  907.58  908.35  38.357143
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love someone to come up with a solution that *doesn't* involve loops, but since everything is sorted I think the performance will actually not be that bad (linear in the lengths of the two dataframes and no memory overhead). I don't know the precise specification of your dataframes, so I'll create some sample ones first.

```
n_a = 11
df_a = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Framecount": list(range(n_a)), "probability": np.random.rand(n_a)}
)

n_b = 6
start = np.linspace(0, n_a, n_b)
end = start + n_a / (n_b - 1) - 1e-5
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"start": start, "end": end, "mean": [np.nan] * n_b})

print(df_a)
    Framecount  probability
0            0     0.099412
1            1     0.492661
2            2     0.043000
3            3     0.382923
4            4     0.208177
5            5     0.110007
6            6     0.369756
7            7     0.324723
8            8     0.702838
9            9     0.182167
10          10     0.578837

print(df_b)
   start       end  mean
0    0.0   2.19999  NaN
1    2.2   4.39999  NaN
2    4.4   6.59999  NaN
3    6.6   8.79999  NaN
4    8.8  10.99999  NaN
5   11.0  13.19999  NaN
```

Now I'll loop through the dataframes, aggregating all values between the current `start` and `end` and assign in the corresponding row in `df_b`:

```
i = j = 0
while i < n_a and j < n_b:
    # seek to next row of df_b where start <= df_a[i]
    while i < n_a and df_a.loc[i, "Framecount"] < df_b.loc[j, "start"]:
        i += 1

    accum = 0
    count = 0
    while i < n_a and df_a.loc[i, "Framecount"] < df_b.loc[j, "end"]:
        accum += df_a.loc[i, "probability"]
        count += 1
        i += 1

    df_b.loc[j, "mean"] = accum / count
    j += 1

print(df_b)
   start       end      mean
0    0.0   2.19999  0.211691
1    2.2   4.39999   0.29555
2    4.4   6.59999  0.239882
3    6.6   8.79999  0.513781
4    8.8  10.99999  0.380502
5   11.0  13.19999      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm confused. What are n_a and n_b?

Comment: @connor449 just the lengths of the made up dataframes. For you they’d both be 906.

Comment: I'm getting this error:` ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-282-d02c0d8644d3> in <module>
     17         i += 1
     18 
---> 19     df_b.loc[j, "mean"] = accum / count
     20     j += 1
     21 

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`